# Illegal assignment from JSONGenerator to JSONGenerator

Tags: apex, json

I have written a code for generating json

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

    // Create a list of integers to write to the JSON string.
    List<integer> intlist = new List<integer>();
    intlist.add(1);
    intlist.add(2);
    intlist.add(3);

    // Create an object to write to the JSON string.
    A x = new A('X');

    // Write data to the JSON string.
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeNumberField('abc', 1.21);
    gen.writeStringField('def', 'xyz');
    gen.writeFieldName('ghi');
    gen.writeStartObject();
```

and I got error

```
Illegal assignment from JSONGenerator to JSONGenerator
```

I am new in Apex. any help will really helpful form me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have created an APEX class called JSON or JSONGenerator

This will work in any case (if you have no problems with defining object type A)

```
system.JSONGenerator gen = system.JSON.createGenerator(true);

// Create a list of integers to write to the JSON string.
List<integer> intlist = new List<integer>();
intlist.add(1);
intlist.add(2);
intlist.add(3);

// Create an object to write to the JSON string.
A x = new A('X');

// Write data to the JSON string.
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeNumberField('abc', 1.21);
gen.writeStringField('def', 'xyz');
gen.writeFieldName('ghi');
gen.writeStartObject();
```